# Azure Data Factory - Stored Procedure - Error code ActionTimedOut & Details Activity timed out

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, azure-data-factory

I have a stored procedure activity in my Azure Data Factory pipeline.

The pipeline frequently fails due to the stored procedure activity timing out after duration ~ 01:30:00. However, the pipeline failure very often resolves itself quickly by re-running itself. I would like to find out the cause for the failed pipeline.

The error details are:

> Error details
> Error code ActionTimedOut
> Failure type User configuration issue
> Details Activity timed out
> Source Pipeline *pipeline name*

The error details don't tell me very much about what could be the root cause for the error.

Does anybody have a suggestion where I could start debugging the problem and what are common causes for stored procedure timeouts in Azure Data Factory pipelines? Or where I could find more information about the error message?

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

Please checkout the timeout value on the activity itself . More over you can set the retry with a wait time also which may help you .

[image]

Comment: Have the same issue but the timeout values look the same as in the picture, so no help on that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps on this case, mine was an error related with executing a SP, but the error code was the same.

Turns out that my ADF connection user did not have write, execute permissions on the database.
I just added with the GRANT command and it worked.

```
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [<ADF_DB_USER>];
GO
```